# Считывание данных из файла

Tags: php

Нужно сделать интернет магазин, данные для которого считываются из файла. Структура файла представлена на картинке.

С данным кодом у меня считывается в Kat - только womenclosing, а мне надо что бы считывался список : womenclothing, accessories, menclothing, cosmetics. При этом еще нужно чтобы данные не повторялись построчно. То есть на  главной  странице  у  меня  должен  быть  выведен  список  категорий(скрин 2). Скрин  2 - пример  выполнен  на  awk,  теперь мне  надо  реализовать  на PHP

```
<?php
$files=file_get_contents( "file.txt");
list($kat, $vid, $count, $cost, $param) = explode(" ", $files); 
for ($i=0;$i<count($kat);$i++){ 
echo $kat; 
}

?>
```

[image: скрин 1]

[image: скрин 2]

Comment: Доброго времени суток !
Если не принципиально, попробуйте считывать данные из базы данных или JSON файла.

Comment: "у меня получается только строку считать одно значение " - извините, не совсем понял эту фразу.

Comment: Из БД  по  заданию  нельзья,  только  из  файла  нужно

Comment: @Prizrak771 попробуйте так:
`$files = file('file.txt');

foreach ($files as $string) {
    echo "<i>$string</i><br />";
}`

Comment: @Эдуард таким образом читается весь файл, а мне нужно только первый столбец

Comment: @Prizrak771 теперь понятно -- запостил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы получить первое слово каждой строки текст файла, необходимо прочитать текст файл в массив, и пройтись по массиву циклом, при этом разбивать каждую строку файла по пробелу с помощью функции explode(), а в браузер отправлять только первый элемент из временного массива:

```
$files = file('file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

foreach ($files as $string) {
    echo '<i>'. explode(' ', $string)[0] .'</i><br />';
}
```

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую